# After hiding TabBar can't touch on the area behind the TabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I use a TabBarController on my app, in one of the main views (aViewController) i push another controller (bViewController), and hide the TabBar using self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;

bViewController have a button at the same place where the tabBar was, and it doesn't catch the touch event.

I have tried placing the button in different places of bViewController, and the area where the tabBar was supposed to be is the only place where touch event is not detected.

I have tried using bViewController outside the tabBarController and it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

When i press a button on aViewController i call

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aViewToBView" sender:self];
```

aViewToBview is a push segue declared on storyboard

Comment: do you present bViewController modally or push it?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I met the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: couldn't solve it, i just placed the button above the tabBar area, looks ugly, but have to live with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you cannot touch the views underneath the tab bar.

However, if you hide the tab bar and then add a subview to it, the view can then receive user interaction!

This worked for me:

```
// Create a button that is at the very bottom of the screen
CGFloat buttonHeight = 45.0f;
UIButton *finishButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
          0, 
          self.view.frame.size.height - self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height - buttonHeight,
          self.view.frame.size.width,
          buttonHeight)];
//...more initialization of the button...

//Here is our solution:
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:finishButton];
```

Comment: It is not the best solution in my case, but it works, thanks.

Comment: @gomezluisj why is it not the best solution? Can you elaborate?

Comment: creating the button programmatically means i can't use my storyboard's constrains, so i would need to set them programmatically too which is a pain.

Comment: I see. You should still be able to create it through storyboard. However at runtime you have to just include that last line where you add the sub view to the tabbarcontroller.view

Comment: This solution doesn't provide any help for cases where the view is not solely within the tabbar's frame. I'm working with a UITableView subclass, for instance, which extends to the end of the screen when teh tab bar is hidden; the bottom is untouchable.

Comment: @Ryan when the tab bar is hidden, try setting userInteractionEnabled = false on it. This should allow you to pass touches to the view underneath.

Comment: @JulioVasquez do you have experience with this working? I have set up an observer and confirmed via the console the userInteractionEnabled property is being set but touches are not being passed. I've also tried to take advantage of the recursive hitTest system, but neither have yielded results (specific case is a uitableview which extends to the tabBar's origin.y). Not that I believe it to be relevant, but I am not using autoLayout